# Access thread and run a method inside Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, class

Here's my code:

```
public class DJ {
    static Thread djThread = new DJPlayThread();

    public static void play(){
        djThread.start();
    }
}
```

But once that thread is started, how can I run a method that is inside of the `DJPlayThread` class?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually mean "How do I define the code that will be executed by the new Thread?"

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  I suspect you're not grasping how to use Threads, but without knowing what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to give you pointers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion. I have a method called stop() which is in DJPlayThread that I need to call from outside the thread class, if that makes any sense.

Comment: The Thread class already has a stop method.

Comment: @johncarl - That method is depreciated, and from what I've read, unsafe to use. I mean a method I made in the class called stop(). I can rename it to whatever though, like stopMusic().

Comment: Right, just about to say that... coming up with an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to do what you ask:

```
public class ThreadControl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable("MyRunnable");
        Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        myRunnable.whoAmI();//call method from within thread

        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        myRunnable.isStopped.set(true);//stop thread
    }

 static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public String threadName;
        public AtomicBoolean isStopped=new AtomicBoolean(false);

        public MyRunnable() {
        }

        public MyRunnable(String threadName) {
            this.threadName = threadName;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread started, threadName=" + this.threadName + ", hashCode="
                    + this.hashCode());

            while (!this.isStopped.get()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("Thread looping, threadName=" + this.threadName + ", hashCode="
                        + this.hashCode());
            }
        }

        public void whoAmI() {
            System.out.println("whoAmI, threadName=" + this.threadName + ", hashCode="
                    + this.hashCode());
        }

    }

}
```

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/549659/java/java/you-access-methods-thread-target

Comment: Ahh thanks, I think this will work. Once I confirm I will accept :)

Comment: Using a boolean this way may work in the trivial case, but will lead to subtle and hard to fix bugs when run with heavy load.

Comment: @johncarl in all technicality it was a sample and the boolean had nothing to do with the question (used) it for neatness and for stopping the thread

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I think it has everything to do with the question.  We should provide complete examples.  In this case, you just need to use an AtomicBoolean, make isStopped volitile or provider a synchronized getter/setter pair for thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DJ {
    private DJPlayThread djThread = new DJPlayThread();

    public void play() throws InterruptedException {
        djThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        djThread.stopMusic();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            new DJ().play();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class DJPlayThread extends Thread{

    private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running.get()){
            System.out.println("Playing Music");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic(){
        //be careful about thread safety here
        running.set(false);
    }
}
```

Should print out:

```
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music 
Playing Music
```

Be very careful about the thread safety when exchanging information between threads.  There are some weird things that happen when accessing and modifying variables across thread contexts.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  Thanks David.  Just finished re-reading Java Concurrency in Practice so Im attuned to thread safety.